# DeepXDE: Cannot feed value of shape (5950, 2) for Tensor Placeholder_86:0, which has shape (None, 278)

Tags: neural-network, python-3.10

I'm trying to learn to use DeepXDE by solving the heat equation. Luckily there is an example that I've been able to compare with but I get an error regarding shapes mismatching I haven't been able to resolve. I'm using Python 3.10.2.

I still struggle to understand the shape some commands are expecting. I've tried to guide myself with the example and having in mind the problem of solving the heat equation having a dataset of daily ground temperatures at certain depths. I use this data set to constraint as IC/BCs.

train_T initial's shape is (2557 time steps, 278 cell depths) before transformations.I added a random generated array that I normalize for the sake of the network training.

I'm also not sure about how I specify the training points inside the domain, boundaries, etc.

I'd like to know where the next shape mismatch error is coming from.

P.S. The last code lines will plot, save and generate some files you might not want.

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import netCDF4 as nc
import deepxde as dde
import tensorflow as tf

train_T = np.random.rand(2557, 278)              
train_mean=np.mean(train_T, axis=0, keepdims=True )
train_std =np.std(train_T, axis=0, keepdims=True)


train_T = (train_T-train_mean)/train_std

train_days, cells=np.shape(train_T)
time_steps=np.arange(train_days)


ic_T = train_T[0,:].reshape(-1,1)   # First day profile as IC
ubc_T= train_T[:,0]                 # First/last cells as upper/lower BC
lbc_T=train_T[:,-1]

ub_depth,lb_depth = (depth[0],depth[-1])  # Depths of first and last cell

points=[]
values=[]

for day in range(train_days):
    points.extend([[day, ub_depth], [day, lb_depth]])
    values.extend([ubc_T[day], lbc_T[day]])

values = np.asarray(values).reshape(-1)

a=0.4
def pde(x,y):
    dy_t=dde.grad.jacobian(y,x,i=0,j=0)
    dy_zz = dde.grad.hessian(y, x, i=1, j=1)
    return dy_t - a* dy_zz

# Computational geometry:
geom = dde.geometry.Interval(0, depth[-1])
timedomain = dde.geometry.TimeDomain(0, train_days)
geomtime = dde.geometry.GeometryXTime(geom, timedomain)


bc=dde.icbc.PointSetBC(points, values, shuffle=False)
ic = dde.icbc.IC(geomtime, lambda x: ic_T,lambda _ , on_initial: on_initial)

data = dde.data.TimePDE(
    geomtime,
    pde,
    [bc, ic],
    num_domain=cells,  
    num_boundary=2,  
    num_initial=cells,  
    num_test=cells,  
)

net = dde.nn.FNN([cells] + [20] * 2 + [cells-2], "tanh", "Glorot normal")
model = dde.Model(data, net)

model.compile("adam", lr=1e-3)
model.train(iterations=20000)
model.compile("L-BFGS")
losshistory, train_state = model.train()

# Plot/print the results
dde.saveplot(losshistory, train_state, issave=True, isplot=True)
X, y_true = gen_testdata()
y_pred = model.predict(X)
f = model.predict(X, operator=pde)
print("Mean residual:", np.mean(np.absolute(f)))
print("L2 relative error:", dde.metrics.l2_relative_error(y_true, y_pred))
np.savetxt("test.dat", np.hstack((X, y_true, y_pred)))
```

This is the error I get:

```
Warning: 278 points required, but 286 points sampled.
Compiling model...
Building feed-forward neural network...
'build' took 0.034132 s

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_1789121/2863646270.py in <module>
     61 
     62 model.compile("adam", lr=1e-3)
---> 63 model.train(iterations=20000)
     64 model.compile("L-BFGS")
     65 losshistory, train_state = model.train()

~/jupyter_py3.10.2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deepxde/utils/internal.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     20     def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
     21         ts = timeit.default_timer()
---> 22         result = f(*args, **kwargs)
     23         te = timeit.default_timer()
     24         if config.rank == 0:

~/jupyter_py3.10.2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deepxde/model.py in train(self, iterations, batch_size, display_every, disregard_previous_best, callbacks, model_restore_path, model_save_path, epochs)
    634         self.train_state.set_data_train(*self.data.train_next_batch(self.batch_size))
    635         self.train_state.set_data_test(*self.data.test())
--> 636         self._test()
    637         self.callbacks.on_train_begin()
    638         if optimizers.is_external_optimizer(self.opt_name):

~/jupyter_py3.10.2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deepxde/model.py in _test(self)
    823             self.train_state.y_pred_train,
    824             self.train_state.loss_train,
--> 825         ) = self._outputs_losses(
    826             True,
    827             self.train_state.X_train,

~/jupyter_py3.10.2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deepxde/model.py in _outputs_losses(self, training, inputs, targets, auxiliary_vars)
    539         if backend_name == "tensorflow.compat.v1":
    540             feed_dict = self.net.feed_dict(training, inputs, targets, auxiliary_vars)
--> 541             return self.sess.run(outputs_losses, feed_dict=feed_dict)
    542         if backend_name == "tensorflow":
    543             outs = outputs_losses(inputs, targets, auxiliary_vars)

~/jupyter_py3.10.2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    970 
    971     try:
--> 972       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
    973                          run_metadata_ptr)
    974       if run_metadata:

~/jupyter_py3.10.2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1187           if (not is_tensor_handle_feed and
   1188               not subfeed_t.get_shape().is_compatible_with(np_val.shape)):
-> 1189             raise ValueError(
   1190                 f'Cannot feed value of shape {str(np_val.shape)} for Tensor '
   1191                 f'{subfeed_t.name}, which has shape '

ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (5950, 2) for Tensor Placeholder_86:0, which has shape (None, 278)
```

Please let me know if you needed more information.